# Conductas de buena programación

Tags: aplicación-web, java-ee

Tengo este código:

```
@Override
public boolean comprobarEmail(String email) {
    Connection conexion;
    PreparedStatement preparada = null;
    ResultSet resultado = null;
    conexion = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    String sql = "select email from usuarios where email = ?";
    try {
        preparada = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparada.setString(1, email);
        resultado = preparada.executeQuery();
        resultado.next();
        resultado.getString("email");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("ComprobarEmail - ErrorCode: " + ex.getErrorCode() + " - SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState() + " - Message: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        Utilidades.cerrarPSyRSyS(preparada, resultado, null);
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Es un objeto DAO que es llamado por un servlet que es llamado por AJAX cuando alguien se está registrando en mi página web, su función es comprobar si el email escrito por el cliente existe o no en la base de datos.

La cuestión es:
Mi compañero prefiere guardar una variable boolean y hacer un solo `return`.
Mi posición es que prefiero ahorrarme una variable(espacio en memoria, y de mucha gente, porque es una aplicación web) y poner varios `return`.

Aparte pero parecido pasa igual en los servlets, yo prefiero poner muchos `request.getRequestDispatcher` y él pone una variable String url(espacio en memoria y de mucha gente) y un solo `request.getRequestDispatcher` al final del servlet.

La aplicación se programa en páginas JSP, servlets JAVA y base de datos MySQL.

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma correcta de programar ya que por aquí se mueve la crema de los programadores, gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de programar es la que funcione y sea mantenible.

A tener en cuenta:

- En general, y sobre todo para lenguajes de alto nivel, el coste de usar una variable es mínimo, *suponienda que exista*. De hecho, es posible para el compilador reorganizar el código para que no lo necesite/reaprovechar la posición de memoria de otra variable que ya no es necesaria/etc. Eso no debería ser un argumento.

  Además, aparte de las variables que defines, el compilador también reserva espacio para expresiones intermedia (como crees que se ejecuta `int a = b + c + d + e` si no hay un valor intermedio que guarde `b + c`, luego `b + c + d`, etc.
- Lo que importa es la legibilidad y la mantenibilidad. En ese sentido, sí que hay consejos de buenas prácticas que piden porque solo exista un único `return`(*single exit point*), con la idea de evitar que, al leer el código, alguien se salte un `return` enmedio y piense que la lógica se ejecuta de forma distinta a como lo hace.

  Pero eso es una idea general, y no debe afectar a la legibilidad.

Y ¿cuál es la forma correcta? Pues dependerá un poco de opiniones, pero es importante que sea coherente cuando trabaja mucha gente en el mismo proyecto. Por ejemplo, yo tiendo a violar esa norma:

- Al comprobar condiciones especiales antes del bloque principal:

  ```
  public void miMetodoHaceAlgo(String algo, String otraCosa) {

    if (algo == null) {
       return;
    }

    if ("Hola".equals(otraCosa)) {
       return;
    }

    ...
  ```
- En cláusulas `catch`, ya que *capturan excepciones que lo que supone una ruptura del flujo del programa*.

  ```
      ...
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // log, lo que sea
      return false;
    }
  ```
- Cuando es notablemente más complicado la solución con *single exit point* que sin.

  ```
    boolean tenemosResultado = false;
    int resultado;

    while (!tenemosResultado) {
      // Un trozo de lógica para calcular condicionA
      if (condicionA) {
         tenemosResultado = true;
         resultado = resultadoA;
      }

      if (!tenemosResultado) {
        // Otro trozo de lógica para calcular condicionB
        if (condicionB) {
          tenemosResultado = true;
          resultado = resultadoB;
        }
      }
    }
    return resultado;
  ```

Personalmente, pienso que no es mala práctica en sí, pero:

- No debería usarse ciegamente.
- Las situaciones en donde es útil se corresponden con trozos de código que son complicados; aunque no siempre se puede hacer conviene pensar si la solución no pasa por refactorizar y simplificar esos fragmentos.

Pero al final la cuestión es que tu compañero y tú os pongáis de acuerdo.